# How to search by word clause with some spacial "-,+" char in fulltext search query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, full-text-search

I have data stored like `e-mail address: some@domain.com`, and I want to search by `e-mail` with fulltext search technique. I have the following:

```
select * from ticket
where MATCH(ticket_body) AGAINST('e-mail' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But, it gives me empty output. please help anybody..